# Problem with factoring $-x^3+x^2+5x+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I want to factor the following polynomial:
$$-x^3+x^2+5x+3$$

I started by using the rational root theorem and got the factors $\pm1$ and $\pm3$ for the constant. Via synthetic division i found out that $(x-3)$ is a factor. Now i'm stuck with the equation $(x-3)\cdot(-x^2-2x-1)$.

I tried using the sum of the factors of $-1$ but it turns out that they are $0$ and not $-2$.

$$-1=1\cdot(-1) \implies 1+(-1)=0$$

I read that if the sum is equal to the number in front of the $x^1$ (in my case $-2$) these numbers are the missing factors so for example $(x-1)\cdot(x+1)$.

I know that there are other ways to factor my polynomial, but I want to understand why it is not working in my case or what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for any type of help :)

Comment: $-x^2-2x-1=-(x+1)^2$

Comment: i know that but i want to understand why it is not working with the sum of its divisors

Comment: First of all, as per Vieta formulae, if you are looking for zeros of $ax^2+bx+c$, the sum of the zeros $x_1+x_2$ is *not* $-b$, it is $\frac{-b}{a}$. So in your case, the sum is $\frac{-(-2)}{-1}=-2$. This matches the point that both zeros are $-1$ (i.e. you have a double zero). This is the second point - the zeros need not be different, even though all of them need to satisfy the rational root theorem.

Comment: You need only factor out $\space -1\space $ to make your approach work.

$$
-x^3+x^2+5x+3\\
=(x - 3)(-x^2-2x-1)
\\=\big(x - 3\big) \big(x + 1\big)^2\big(-1\big)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of the *roots* of a *monic* polynomial $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ is $-a_{n-1}$, *if the roots are counted with their multiplicities*. In your case, you have $-x^2-2x-1$, which is not monic. But its roots are the roots of $x^2+2x+1$, which *is* monic. And this polynomial only has one root, $-1$, which is a double root. So, the sum of the roots, counted with their multiplicities, is $-2$.